# How should I map nice looking "display values" to a JDL enum?

Tags: jhipster

If I have an enum in my JDL file that looks like this:

```
enum Country {
  UNITED_STATES_OF_AMERICA,
  CANADA,
  MEXICO
}
```

When I use the enum in an entity:

```
entity Foo {
  country Country required
}
```

, the resulting dropdown in `foo-update.component.html` is:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" [(ngModel)]="foo.country" id="field_country"  required>
  <option value="UNITED_STATES_OF_AMERICA">UNITED_STATES_OF_AMERICA</option>
  <option value="CANADA">CANADA</option>
  <option value="MEXICO">MEXICO</option>
</select>
```

Is there a better way of mapping the `value` with a "display value" than just manually making the adjustment in `foo-update.component.html`? I'd also have to make some kind of Angular Pipe in order for it to look right on `foo.component.html` and `foo-detail.component.html`

Ideally, the JDL enum would let me do something like:

```
enum Country {
  UNITED_STATES_OF_AMERICA("United States"),
  CANADA("Canada"),
  MEXICO("Mexico")
}
```

Is this being thought of already? If not I'm happy to help with a PR. I know it would be quite a bit of work since it not only requires changes to the JDL spec but also changes to the Angular and React generators.

Comment: I did not check recently but I thought that enums could be translated, check src/main/webapp/i18n unless maybe you have disabled i18n  option

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks! That's a good point, that I hadn't thought of. I did not turn on Internationalization for this particular app. Although, it seems like Internationalization is a pretty heavy-handed way of dealing with this. In my opinion, there should still be a simple way to do it even with i18n turned off.